# Retrieve 3rd MAX salary in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm a novice. I have the following Employee table.

```
ID  Name  Country  Salary  ManagerID
```

I retrieved the 3rd max salary using the following.

```
select name , salary From (
    select name, salary from 
    employee sort by salary desc limit 3)
    result sort by salary limit 1;
```

How to do the same to display 3rd max salary for each country? can we use OVER (`PARTITION BY country`)? I tried looking in the languageManual Windowing and Analytics but I'm finding it difficult to understand. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track with windowing functions.  `row_number()` is a good function to use here.

```
select name, salary
from (
  select name
    , salary
    , row_number() over (partition by country order by salary desc) idx
  from employee ) x
where idx = 3
```

when you order by salary, make sure that it is a numerical type, or it will not be sorted correctly.