# hive sql inner join - how to get sum & row_num in same query

Tags: hive, hiveql

i've 2 tables product & psales, data in the tables is as shown below

```
select * from psales;
+-------------+---------------+--+
| psales.pid  | psales.sales  |
+-------------+---------------+--+
| 1           | 100           |
| 1           | 150           |
| 1           | 200           |
| 2           | 75            |
| 2           | 45            |
| 2           | 145           |
| 3           | 176           |
| 3           | 99            |
| 1           | 27            |
| 4           | 51            |
+-------------+---------------+--+

select * from product;
+--------------+----------------+--+
| product.pid  | product.pname  |
+--------------+----------------+--+
| 1            | p1             |
| 2            | p2             |
| 3            | p3             |
| 4            | p4             |
+--------------+----------------+--+
```

Objective is to get the product with 2nd highest combined sales.

Here is the query i'm currently using to get the product with highest combined sales (working fine)

```
select p1.pname, p1.total_sales
from (select p.pid as pid, p.pname as pname, s.sales as sales,  
      sum(s.sales) over (partition by p.pid order by p.pid) as total_sales 
      from product p
      inner join psales s on (p.pid = s.pid) 
      order by total_sales desc) p1 
limit 1;
```

How do i get the product with the 2nd highest combined sales ?

When i try to get the row_num in the inner query, it gives me error shown below :

```
select p1.pname as pname, p1.total_sales as total_sales, row_num() over (partition by pname order by pname) as rownum 
from (select p.pid as pid, p.pname as pname, s.sales as sales,  
      sum(s.sales) over (partition by p.pid order by p.pid) as total_sales, 
      row_num() over (partition by p.pid) as rownum 
      from product p 
      inner join psales s on (p.pid = s.pid) 
      order by total_sales desc) p1 
where rownum =2;
```

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
>           Underlying error: Invalid function row_num (state=42000,code=40000)

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Please format code readably.

Comment: ORDER BY without LIMIT in a subquery does nothing--tables have no row order, query result sets [sic] are ordered. PS If you get a syntax error then chop your code down until you don't.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve 3rd MAX salary in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488530/retrieve-3rd-max-salary-in-hive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` to rank the sum per pid,name combination.

```
select p1.pname,p1.pid,p1.total_sales
from (select p.pid, p.pname,sum(s.sales) as total_sales,
      dense_rank() over(order by sum(s.sales) desc) as rnk 
      from product p 
      join psales s on p.pid = s.pid
      group by p.pid,p.pname
     ) p1
where rnk=2
```

Comment: thanks, this works .. btw, in trying to understand where i should use the OVER clause and where i should not, i mis-spelled row_number() as row_num().

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` function in the upper subquery. And it seems you do not need analytic `sum()`, simple `group by` will do:

```
select p1.pname, p1.pid, p1.total_sales
  from
(
select p1.pname, p1.pid, p1.total_sales, 
       row_number() over (order by total_sales  desc) rn
  from 
     (select p.pid, p.pname, sum(s.sales) as total_sales 
        from product p 
             inner join psales s on p.pid = s.pid
        group by p.pid, p.pname
     )p1
)s
where rn=2
;
```

Use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` if you want to select all products with the same sales.